# Sort an array of custom objects in descending order on an int property

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to sort my array in descending order by year of birth.
My array has two other elements which are of type String.
So, as an example the person who was born in the earliest year, such as 1939, would be at the top, then so on.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StudentInformationTest
{
public static void main (String [] args){ 
    StudentInformation[] studentInfo = new StudentInformation[10];

    studentInfo[0] = new StudentInformation("Student A",1971, "BSc FDIT");
    studentInfo[1] = new StudentInformation("Student B",1964, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[2] = new StudentInformation("Student C",1996, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[3] = new StudentInformation("Student D",1939, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[4] = new StudentInformation("Student E",1945, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[5] = new StudentInformation("Student F",1991, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[6] = new StudentInformation("Student G",1987, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[7] = new StudentInformation("Student H",1968, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[8] = new StudentInformation("Student I",1968, "BSc FDIT"); 
    studentInfo[9] = new StudentInformation("Student J",1973, "BSc FDIT"); 

    printInfo(studentInfo);
    printAge(studentInfo);
}
public static void printInfo(StudentInformation studentInfo[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < studentInfo.length; i++){
        System.out.println(studentInfo[i].getStudentName() + " " +   studentInfo[i].getBirthDate() + " " + studentInfo[i].getProgrammeOfStudy());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

 }

}
```

Once I manage to print the birth years in descending order I also need to show the student name and the university modules they are doing. 
I know other questions have been asked how to do this but I have not been able to see one with other objects.
This is a class session so please forgive any errors in my code.

Comment: if sorting is imprtant then why are you using array? Use `ArraList` instead.Sorting will be easier with `Collection`s

Comment: Pick an appropriate version of java.util.Arrays.sort.

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated, but this could be a way to exercise a sorting algorithm suitable for arrays. Can't understand why it's downvoted

Comment: The formulation of the question is wrong. This is not an array of either ints or Strings. The array hasn't got "two other elements that are of type String", it is a homogeneous array of `StudentInformation`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Apologies. I will make sure the question will make better sense in future. Still learning. =]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use a `Comparator` and an `ArrayList`.

### In Java 8

Use the new default and static methods on `Comparator`!

```
ArrayList<StudentInformation> infos = new ArrayList<StudentInformation>();
// fill array
Collections.sort(infos, 
    Comparator.comparingInt(StudentInformation::getBirthYear).reversed());
```

It's a brave new world! :)

Or—still better than Java 7—use [lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax)!

```
ArrayList<StudentInformation> infos = new ArrayList<StudentInformation>();
// fill array
Collections.sort(infos, (s1, s2) ->
    Integer.compare(s2.getBirthYear(), s1.getBirthYear()));
```

### In Java 7

Use anonymous inner classes.

```
class StudentDateComparator implements Comparator<StudentInformation> {
    public int compare(StudentInformation s1, StudentInformation s2) {
        return Integer.compare(s2.getBirthYear(), s1.getBirthYear());
    }
}

ArrayList<StudentInformation> infos = new ArrayList<StudentInformation>();
// fill array
Collections.sort(infos, new StudentDateComparator());
```

### Explanation

What the `Comparator` does is allows anything to compare two objects of the given type (in this case, `StudentInformation`). You could also make `StudentInformation` implement `Comparable<StudentInformation>`, but this way is probably better because there is more than one way to compare student informations (by date, as here, but also by first name, last name, number of classes enrolled, etc.).

By swapping the order of `s1` and `s2` in the comparator, we induce a reverse order. Another way to do this would be to negate the `compare` call in the normal order, or to use a normal comparator and wrap it in `Collections.reverseOrder`.

---

You could also do this with a standard array.

```
StudentInformation[] infos = new StudentInformation[10];
// fill array
Arrays.sort(infos, new StudentDateComparator());
```

Comment: Thanks it sort the arraylist but in ascending order.But looking for descending order sorting.(now after sorting it display as 0,1,2....)

Comment: @blackjack I've added a better solution (`Comparator.comparingInt(StudentInformation::getBirthYear).reversed()`) and edited the original one to be more clearly correct. This work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In the Java land, there is the `Comparable<E>` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
interface Comparable<E> {
  public int compareTo(E other);
}
```

You should make your `StudentInfo` implement `Comparable<StudentInfo>`, implement `compareTo(StudentInfo other)` according to your requirements, and either use methods from the standard library (but this will require a `Comparator` instead) or some sorting algorithm suitable for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `StudentInformation` class implement `Comparable`. Then you must implement a method [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29). This method defines how and when two objects of the class are treated equal, smaller or bigger.

With this property clearly defined you can use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) utility to sort your collection.